# How to get the spec of a machine on Linux?

Tags: linux, memory, cpu

I am interested in getting the spec of a machine, because I am thinking getting a similar server.

What I am mostly interested in knowing is the number of cores / CPUs / etc., the amount of memory, the speed of the CPUs, the CPU cache size, and any other detail which is important for performance.

My question is two-fold:

1. Which parameters should I be interested in other than the ones I specified above?
2. Is there an easy way to read them off the machine in Linux? cat /proc/cpuinfo reveals a lot about the CPUs, for example... What about memory (would rather not rely on top), etc?

Comment: Why not just research current gen CPUs and find one that fits your needs that way?

Comment: Because the server I am using will definitely get me a good idea of the kind of thing I need, and it wasn't bought too a long ago. It will help me focus my search later.

Comment: You can try `lshw`, it compiles available information into a single output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lscpu` will give you CPU information.

You might have to research further for other attributes (such as looking at the manufacturer's website) though `lscpu` will tell you a lot.

Other commands that give you hardware info would be `lshw`, `lspci`, `lsusb`, `dmidecode`, and `lsscsi`.

`free` tells you the total amount of memory accessible to Linux.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo dmesg | less
```

Will give you all of the kernel's output from booting, which will describe the hardware in the box.